# Spring POST controller request body as controller variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Usually, we get request body as a parameter of controller methods. Spring binds the body to the type of the variable.

I want the request body as a property of the controller so that other private methods can access it.

```
public class UserController {

    private String body;    // Request body should automatically bind to this String.  

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody String body) {
        // I know I can do like: this.body = body.
        // But don't want to do that.
    }

    private someMethod() {
        // Give me access of request body please....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are by default singleton scoped beans (created once per container initialisation). Assigning request body (which changes in every request) to something which is created once and can be used everywhere can lead you to serious trouble. If you are just looking to apply some logic in controller by using private method, you can pass the body as argument to that method like this.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody String body) {
    someMethod(body);
}

private void someMethod(String body) {
    // voila! you have the request body here
}
```